# How do I set a specific font for Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

I want to use the same configuration for both Ubuntu and Windows, so I want to share my `~/.emacs` between boxes. I'd like, however, to use the Consolas font in Windows, and Ubuntu Mono font in Ubuntu.

How can I autodetect which OS emacs is running in, and define the font code conditionally on the environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the `system-type` and use `set-frame-font` accordingly.

Here is a short example:

```el
(setq my-prefered-font
      (cond ((eq system-type 'windows-nt) "consolas")
            ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux) "mono")
            (t nil)))

(when my-prefered-font
  (set-frame-font my-prefered-font nil t))
```

Note, that you can also set font size. For example I do `(setq my-prefered-font "Hack-10")`.

Hint: I found `list-fontsets` useful to list available fonts.

And one last note, I do the following to set system specific configurations in my `init.el`:

```el
(load-file (expand-file-name
            (cond ((eq system-type 'windows-nt) "windows.el")
                  ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux) "linux.el")
                  (t "default-system.el"))
            user-emacs-directory))
```

with `windows.el`, `linux.el`and `default-system.el` in folder `~\.emacs.d` with all the system specific stuff.

Comment: I really like your last suggestion, but it comes back with the following error:

`Symbol's function definition is void: load-with-warning`. Maybe you defined this function? Is there a vanilla way of doing this, without custom functions?

Comment: @philsf You are right, I defined `load-with-warning`. I edited my answer accordingly to avoid the function.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to fix it unsuccesfully, but now I see what I was doing wrong.